# Change Mac App Store download location?

Tags: mac, hard-drive, mac-appstore

I currently have a Windows partition installed on my Mac, for CptS reasons, and since that took up a majority of my storage space, I've been using an external hard drive to save documents and whatnot. I wanted to know if I can download applications from the App Store to my external hard drive. I've read on other forums that it's possible to change the location of the download folder on a Mac, but you have to delete the application if you were to want to update it. I'm not sure if it's possible to assign the download folder to an external hard drive.

Any input would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what your question is.  You stated you know you can move the location of the folder from reading other questions.  Have you tried to move the folder to an external drive?